# Will a method overriden in a subclass still be called when the object of subclass is called as superclass?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Ok lets say I have two classes with the same method(sampleMethod) which is overridden by the child: ObjectParent and ObjectChild

```
ObjectChild ExampleVariable = new ObjectChild();
(ExampleVariable as ObjectParent).sampleMethod();
```

Will this call the sampleMethod from ObjectChild or from ObjectParent??

I think it will call the sampleMethod from ObjectChild, but I want to make sure before I throw down a bunch of code based on that assumption.

Comment: Doesn't Pressing `F11` in visual studio while debugging, will show  the actual flow of process ? (just asking I am new)

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes it does. If he pressed F11 on the second line, the debugger would jump into the child class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this call the sampleMethod from ObjectChild or from ObjectParent?

Assuming it's *really* a virtual method which is properly overridden (rather than just being hidden), it will call the `ObjectChild` implementation. That's the whole point of virtual methods - that you don't need to know the execution-time type at compile-time. For example, I can write a method using `Stream.Read` (e.g. by taking the `Stream` as a parameter) without knowing which *implementation* of `Stream` it will end up using. At execution time that code could end up reading from the network, from memory, from disk... my method's code neither knows nor case.

Short but complete program demonstrating this:

```
using System;

class ObjectParent
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ObjectParent.Foo");
    }
}

class ObjectChild : ObjectParent
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ObjectChild.Foo");
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Simpler code to demonstrate the point
        ObjectParent parent = new ObjectChild();
        parent.Foo(); // Prints ObjectChild.Foo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's overridden (as opposed to hidden), then at runtime the implementation of the child class will be used. That's one of the main points of polymorphism. You don't need to know what the actual runtime type of your object is and can treat it as an instance of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if your sampleMethod is `virtual` and `overriden`.. then yes. But might as well have:

```
ObjectParent ExampleVariable = new ObjectChild();
ExampleVariable.sampleMethod();
```

`virtual` means this method is polymorphic and can be overridden by derived types. `overridden` means the derived class **actually overrides** the implementation of sampleMethod in this case from the base class.
I guess the answers are in the keywords themselves.

Comment: This was harder to understand than the other answers because of the grammar but reflects what I thought and agrees with the other solutions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it calls `ObjectChild.sampleMethod()` as you can easily test against:

```
class ObjectParent
{
    public virtual void sampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent");
    }
}

class ObjectChild : ObjectParent
{
    public override void sampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing certain keywords.. this isn't Java ;)

Comment: Wouldn't this hide the method and in fact actually call the parent method?  Assuming you had the inheritance in the object definition that is.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet said...."Assuming it's really a virtual method which is **properly overridden** (rather than just being hidden), it will call the ObjectChild implementation."

Here it is assumed that you have used virtual keyword before method in parent class and override keyword before method in child class.

Otherwise...there are two things to be considered:

1. whether the method of parent class is just being hidden. To investigate such cases..Please have a look on following links: 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx and 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39.aspx
2. Level of access provided to methods (Sometime it may differ in parent and child).
   Both the override method and the virtual method must have the same access level modifier, but if you have not used those you have choices.

Only after above considerations we can get the conclusion on the situation.